# How do incremental build with only "main" file specified in tsconfig

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do incremental build but with `tsconfig.json` mentioning only one "main" file like

```json
"files": ["app.ts"]
```

And let TypeScript compiler to identify rest of the files from imports.

I do not want to specify patter like `include: ["*"]` because not all files should be included in the compilation output folder - Consider multiple apps, and a common library. Not all apps use all files from common library so they should not be outputed.

Example structure:

```
apps\app1\main.ts
apps\app2\main.ts
apps\app3\main.ts
common\utils.ts
common\email.ts
```

e.g. All apps would be using `utils.ts`, but only `app1` would be using `email.ts` so then the file should be compiled only to the output folder of app1.

This already possible with these commands:

```
tsc --project apps\app1
tsc --project apps\app2
tsc --project apps\app2
```

But it compiles the common project 3 times from scratch. Also it is not incremental. Ideally it should be possible with

`tsc --build apps\app1 apps\app2 apps\app2`

What should be the desired `tsconfig.json` files? It would be also good that it runs already on tsc 4.8 dev version.

Please do not sugest to use build tool, I'm interested in tsc incremental build.

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK `tsc` does not **bundle** your code. You need something like `rollup` or `esbuild` to do this.

Comment: I don't want to bundle, just compile only used files

Comment: It doesn't matter what file it compile. If a file is never `import`d, then the file is never used. On the other hand, the bundle tools not only bundle your code, but also do tree-shaking, so you get a more "clean" output.

Comment: In fact the `tsc` builds the code **incrementally** with with the `--project-` or `-p` flag. (I thought that it works only with `--build` flag.) So this solves half of the problem. But it looks like the `tsc` is not able to accept multiple `tsconfig.json` files as a argument, or multiple -`p` switches. Which is unlike the `--build` command which can build multiple configurations in single pass.